# Fetch data from three tables according to some conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table `student` with huge amount of records. For a student I have other tables `activity` and `action`.

For a single student I have multiple activities in `activity` table and multiple actions in `action` table.

I want to fetch those student records which have any activity and action. And from activity table fetch `max(activity_date)` and fetch action data of `max(action_date)` for all students

[image]

Comment: Post your table structure and some data, and you might get an answer.

Comment: Student table is like this:-
1. Student
• Student_id
• Student_name
• Class
2. Activity
• Id
• Activity_by
• Activity_date
• Student_id
3. Action
• Id
• Action_by
• Action_date
• Student_id
• Action_desc

Comment: [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think below SQl useful to you

```
select t1.student_id, t1.student_name, t1.class, t2.Last_activity_date, t3.Last_action_date, t3.Action_desc

(select student_id, student_name, class from student) as t1  join

(select student_id, max(activity_date) as Last_activity_date group by student_id) as t2 on t2.student_id =t1.student_id join

select student_id, max(actiondate) as Last_action_date, Action_desc  group by student_id) as t3 on t3.student_id =t1.student_id
order by 1
```

Comment: by above query, error occur "Column 'student_id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: so i wrote this...it works fine...........................................................  select t1.student_id, max(activity_date), max (action_date) from student as t1 
left join activity as t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id  left join action as t3 
on t1.student_id  = t3.student_id 
group by t1.student_id

Comment: @Aditi Modified my answer please take a look. can you accept my answer?

Comment: But by this query show all student_id from 'student' table. And my question is fetch only those student records which exist in either 'activity' table or 'action' table

Comment: instead of left join you can use just join. I think your problem will be solve.

Comment: using join i got students who are exist in activity and action both, means and action perform. I want or condition, either exist in activity or action table

Comment: please suggest me other query. Above query will not work according to my requirement

Comment: @aditi definitely I will help you. Give me sample data from all three table and expecting result

Comment: please see the question and click on 'enter image description here' to see the table structure and result also

Comment: @aditi sorry, I am not understand your requirement well. For understanding purpose please provide sample data.

Comment: ,please see the image, sample data is given and result also given. please check it again

Comment: For image see the posted question above

Comment: got the sample table structure or not?

Comment: i got the structure. Modified my answer please check it once.

Comment: if you have any problem. come on skype, skype id: panabakavenkatesh

Comment: this query not work properly. run this query at your side

Comment: this query not work.please suggest me other query for this according to my requirement

Comment: You can your tables here: http://sqlfiddle.com/. It will be easy to work.